# Bezout's Thereon Paradox

Tags: algebraic-geometry, tensors

Let $V^2$, $V^3$ be $2$-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $U_1 = x^2_1 \otimes x^3_1 + x^2_2 \otimes x^3_2$ and $U_2 = x^2_1 \otimes x^3_2$ be elements of $V^2 \otimes V^3$ where $\{x^2_1, x^2_2\}$ and $\{x^3_1, x^3_2\}$ are linearly independent. Let $[U_1]$ denote the projectivization of $U_1$ and let $\langle [U_1], [U_2] \rangle$ denote the projective line generated by $[U_1]$ and $[U_2]$.

I have shown that the projective lines $\langle [U_1], [U_2] \rangle$ and $\langle [x^2_1 \otimes x^3_1],  [x^2_2 \otimes x^3_2] \rangle$ and the  Segre variety of all $2 \times 2$ tensors of determinant $0$ all have no common components and no common intersection points. Doesn't this contradict Bezout's theorem?

These three varieties are generated homogenous polynomials in four variables of degrees $1$, $1$, and $2$ respectively. Bezout's theorem should guarantee that three homogenous equations in four variables with no common components must have at least one common intersection point in complex projective space.

Comment: Assuming I'm interpreting the Segre variety you're talking about correctly, you're asking about the intersection of two lines and a 3-fold in $\Bbb P^5$. There's no reason for them to intersect: intersections are only forced when the sum of the codimensions is less than the dimension of the ambient projective space. Your error lies in the final paragraph: your identification of the equations cutting out your subvarieties is not correct. For instance, a projective line in $\Bbb P^n$ is cut out by $n-1$ linear equations.